# Possible to bend a UISlider in half to make a 90° angle?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uislider

I'm trying to create a `UISlider` that will have the ability to drag upwards, and to the right. Think of the slider looking like a capital `L` with the slider `thumb-button` positioned at the bend after each slide action is performed.

I've looked and found this: [UICircularSlider](https://github.com/Zedenem/UICircularSlider/issues/5)

But it seems too much for what I need done. I'm not sure `UISlider` is the way to go, but it's what comes to mind for easiest functionality.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why does it seem too much? Surely it seems perfect guidance for you to use.

Answer (score 0):

Going with 3rd party libraries is definitely one way to go, but the normal way using all the normal objective C components would be having 2 UISliders, rotate one of the 90 degrees using `CGAffineTransformRotate`. Then you start the second one as the other one ends and hide the ThumbImage on the first one so it kind of gives you the feeling that they are continues. Once again, this way definitely is not a tidy way to do it, just no headaches of working with new libraries.

P.S: You can make your own subclass of UISlider and implement this in that class, so you can reuse it if you needed it again.

Comment: Since he's bouncing the thumb button back to a zero position after every slide, hiding the other thumb button means the other slider will always be nonfunctional.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion:

1. Make 2 sliders, rotate one 90 degrees and hide the thumb.
2. Add a gesture recognizer to the horizontal (active) slider's thumb image and set the direction to UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp.
3. At an up swipe event, show the vertical slider's thumb and hide the horizontal slider's thumb.

On the downside, this method doesn't report the vertical location, so you might wanna use UITouch, call the locationInView method, and update the thumb frame accordingly. Beats the purpose of using a slider, but achieves what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

U can make 2 view to make it.:

1. bottomview that detects rotate gestures
2. topview with image of circular slider in that

Example of control : https://github.com/nathanday/ndrotator